# What happens if I call ParamByName for a parameter that has multiple locations in a query?

Tags: delphi, unidac

I have a runtime created query that may or may not need some specific params to be used more than once. If I use ParamByName in a query like

```
select field1 
from table1 
where field2 = :a 
and field2 in(select field3 from table2 where field3 = :a)
```

What happens when I call

```
MyQuery.ParamByName('a').AsString:= 'something';
```

Will both params be filled?

Comment: The answer would be no, you'll need to use 2 parameters... [Related post](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=1654)

Comment: Or loop through all parameters and assign them depending on their names.

Comment: What did you observe when you tested it?

Comment: It depends on the data access components you're using. `TAdoQuery`, for instance, requires you to assign the value multiple times. The Advantage `TAdsQuery`, on the other hand, allows you to set the parameter once and it will populate all uses of that parameter in the SQL statement. So, as @Rob asked, what happens when you try it with the particular DB access components you're using? (Taking two minutes to write a quick test application is extremely helpful, and most times gives you an answer a thousand times quicker than posting here, formatting, and waiting.)